# Stop function when another function return javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have 3 functions like below:

```js
function1() {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  function2(a);
  function3(b);
}

function2(a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    return alert("test")
  }
}

function3(a) {
  if (a == 2) {
    return alert("test")
  }
}
```

Now i want to prevent `function3()` from running in `function1()` if `function2()` returns something. How is that possible?

Comment: yea sorry mistyped.

Comment: So use `if (!function2(a)) { function3(b) }`? Of course `alert` never returns anything but `undefined`.

Comment: Well, `function2` returns `undefined` always.

Comment: `return alert("test")` doesn’t really make sense. `alert` returns `undefined`.

Comment: please add valid code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If function2 alert comes, then stop calling function3. You cannot `return alert()` as that would result in undefined. Instead let `alert` complete and then `return`. And use that `return` as a condition for the next function call. Below is the updated code:

```js
function function1() {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  if (!function2(a)) {
    function3(b);
  }
}

function function2(a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    alert("function2 alert");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function function3(a) {
  if (a == 2) {
    alert("function3 alert");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function1();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows if `function2` return something if block will trigger. Then it will run `function3`

```
    function1(){
     a = 1;
     b= 2;
      if (!function2(a)) { 
       function3(b) 
      }
    }

    function2(a){

     return a ==1

    }

    function3(a){

     return a ==2

    }
```